# How to make blur effect particles in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I want to make a blur effect particle like this:

[image: particle]

Can I use `shadowBlur` and `shadowOffsetX/shadowOffsetY` to do this? The actual shine will glow and fade a little bit repeatedly, so if I have to write some kind of animation how can I achieve this?

I have tried this code ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8Lb6g/7/)) but it doesn't look like the effect. So I wonder how to blur and glow the particle at the same time?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const ra = window.requestAnimationFrame
  || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
  || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };
  
class Particle {
 constructor(options) {
   this.ctx = options.context;
   this.x = options.x;
    this.y = options.y;
    this.radius = options.radius;
    this.lightSize = this.radius;
    this.color = options.color;
    this.lightDirection = true;
  }
  
 glow() {
    const lightSpeed = 0.5;

    this.lightSize += this.lightDirection ? lightSpeed : -lightSpeed;

    if (this.lightSize > this.radius || this.lightSize < this.radius) {
      this.lightDirection = !this.lightDirection;
    }
  }
  
 render() {
   this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.glow();
   this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.lightSize,
      0, Math.PI * 2
    );
    this.ctx.fill();
    
    this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.62;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius * 0.7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
    this.ctx.shadowBlur = 6;
    this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}

var particle = new Particle({
 context: ctx,
  x: 60,
  y: 80,
  radius: 12,
  color: '#4d88ff'
});

function run() {
 particle.render();
 ra(run);
}

run();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. For a particle system my option is to pre render the blur using a blur filter. A common filter is the convolution filter. It uses a small array to determine the amount neighboring pixels contribute to each pixel of the image. You are best to look up convolution functions to understand it.

[Wiki Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and [Wiki Gaussian blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) for more info.

I am not much of a fan of the standard Gaussian blur or the convolution filter used so in the demo snippet below you can find my version that I think creates a much better blur. The convolution blur filter is procedurally created and is in the imageTools object.

To use create a filter pass an object with properties  `size` the blur amount in pixels and `power` is the strength. Lower powers is less spread on the blur.

```
// image must be loaded or created
var blurFilter = imageTools.createBlurConvolutionArray({size:17,power:1}); // size must be greater than 2 and must be odd eg 3,5,7,9...
// apply the convolution filter on the image. The returned image may be a new 
//image if the input image does not have a ctx property pointing to a 2d canvas context
image = imageTools.applyConvolutionFilter(image,blurFilter);
```

In the demo I create a image, draw a circle on it, copy it and pad it so that there is room for the blur. Then create a blur filter and apply it to the image.

When I render the particles I first draw all the unblurred images, then draw the blurred copies with the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";` so that they have a shine. To vary the amount of shine I use the ctx.globalAlpha to vary the intensity of the rendered blurred image. To improve the FX I have drawn the blur image twice, once with oscillating scale and next at fixed scale and alpha.

The demo is simple, image tools can be found at the top. Then there is some stuff to setup the canvas and handle resize event. Then there is the code that creates the images, and apply the filters. Then starts the render adds some particles and renders everything.

Look in the function `drawParticles` for how I draw everything.
`imageTools` has all the image functions you will need. The `imageTools.applyConvolutionFilter` will apply any filter (sharpen, outline, and many more) you just need to create the appropriate filter. The apply uses the photon count colour model so gives a very high quality result especially for blurs type effects. (though for sharpen you may want to get in and change the squaring of the RGB values, I personally like it other do not)

The blur filter is not fast so if you apply it to larger images It would be best that you break it up in so you do not block the page execution.

A cheap way to get a blur is to copy the image to blur to a smaller version of itself, eg 1/4 then render it scaled back to normal size, the canvas will apply bilinear filtering on the image give a blur effect. Not the best quality but for most situations it is indistinguishable from the more sophisticated blur that I have presented.

**UPDATE**
Change the code so that the particles have a bit of a 3dFX to show that the blur can work up to larger scales. The blue particles are 32 by 32 image and the blur is 9 pixels with the blur image being 50by 50 pixels.

```js
var imageTools = (function () {
    var tools = {
        canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = width;
            c.height = height;
            return c;
        },
        createImage : function (width, height) {
            var image = this.canvas(width, height);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            return image;
        },
        image2Canvas : function (img) {
            var image = this.canvas(img.width, img.height);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            image.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            return image;
        },        
        padImage : function(img,amount){
            var image = this.canvas(img.width + amount * 2, img.height + amount * 2);
            image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
            image.ctx.drawImage(img, amount, amount);
            return image;
        },
        getImageData : function (image) {
            return (image.ctx || (this.image2Canvas(image).ctx)).getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        },
        putImageData : function (image, imgData){
            (image.ctx || (this.image2Canvas(image).ctx)).putImageData(imgData,0, 0);            
            return image;
            
        },
        createBlurConvolutionArray : function(options){
            var i, j, d;  // misc vars
            var filterArray = [];  // the array to create
            var size = options.size === undefined ? 3: options.size;  // array size 
            var center = Math.floor(size / 2);   // center of array
            // the power ? needs descriptive UI options
            var power = options.power === undefined ? 1: options.power;
            // dist to corner
            var maxDist = Math.sqrt(center * center + center * center);
            var dist = 0;    // distance sum
            var sum = 0;     // weight sum
            var centerWeight;   // center calculated weight
            var totalDistance;   // calculated total distance from center
            // first pass get the total distance
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    d = (maxDist-Math.sqrt((center-i)*(center-i)+(center-j)*(center-j)));
                    d = Math.pow(d,power)
                    dist += d;
                }
            }
            totalDistance = dist;   // total distance to all points;
            // second pass get the total weight of all but center
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    d = (maxDist-Math.sqrt((center-i)*(center-i)+(center-j)*(center-j)));
                    d = Math.pow(d,power)
                    d = d/totalDistance;
                    sum += d;
                }
            }
            var scale = 1/sum;
            sum = 0;  // used to check
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    d = (maxDist-Math.sqrt((center-i)*(center-i)+(center-j)*(center-j)));
                    d = Math.pow(d,power)
                    d = d/totalDistance;
                    filterArray.push(d*scale);
                }
            }
            return filterArray;
        },
        applyConvolutionFilter : function(image,filter){
            imageData = this.getImageData(image);
            imageDataResult = this.getImageData(image);
            var w = imageData.width;
            var h = imageData.height;
            var data = imageData.data;
            var data1 = imageDataResult.data;
            var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(filter.length));
            var halfSide = Math.floor(side/2);            
            var r,g,b,a,c;
            for(var y = 0; y < h; y++){
                for(var x = 0; x < w; x++){
                    var ind = y*4*w+x*4;
                    r = 0;
                    g = 0;
                    b = 0;
                    a = 0;
                    for (var cy=0; cy<side; cy++) {
                        for (var cx=0; cx<side; cx++) {
                            var scy = y + cy - halfSide;
                            var scx = x + cx - halfSide;
                            if (scy >= 0 && scy < h && scx >= 0 && scx < w) {
                                var srcOff = (scy*w+scx)*4;
                                var wt = filter[cy*side+cx];
                                r += data[srcOff+0] * data[srcOff+0] * wt;
                                g += data[srcOff+1] * data[srcOff+1] * wt;
                                b += data[srcOff+2] * data[srcOff+2] * wt;
                                a += data[srcOff+3] * data[srcOff+3] * wt;
                            }
                        }
                    }     
    
    
                    data1[ind+0] = Math.sqrt(Math.max(0,r));
                    data1[ind+1] = Math.sqrt(Math.max(0,g));
                    data1[ind+2] = Math.sqrt(Math.max(0,b));
                    data1[ind+3] = Math.sqrt(Math.max(0,a));
                }
            }
            return this.putImageData(image,imageDataResult);
        }

    };
    return tools;
})();

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js begin **/
const CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID = "canv";
const U = undefined;
var w, h, cw, ch; // short cut vars 
var canvas, ctx;
var globalTime = 0; 
var createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals;
var L = typeof log === "function" ? log : function(d){ console.log(d); }
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
    c.id = CANVAS_ELEMENT_ID;    
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c); 
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { canvas = createCanvas(); }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { setGlobals(); }
}
setGlobals = function(){ 
   cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; 
   if(particles && particles.length > 0){
      particles.length = 0;
   }
}



resizeCanvas(); // create and size canvas
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); // add resize event

const IMAGE_SIZE = 32;
const IMAGE_SIZE_HALF = 16;
const GRAV = 2001;
const NUM_PARTICLES = 90;
var background = imageTools.createImage(8,8);
var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,8);
grad.addColorStop(0,"#000");
grad.addColorStop(1,"#048");
background.ctx.fillStyle = grad;
background.ctx.fillRect(0,0,8,8);
var circle = imageTools.createImage(IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE);
circle.ctx.fillStyle = "#5BF";
circle.ctx.arc(IMAGE_SIZE_HALF, IMAGE_SIZE_HALF, IMAGE_SIZE_HALF -2,0, Math.PI * 2);
circle.ctx.fill();
var blurFilter = imageTools.createBlurConvolutionArray({size:9,power:1}); // size must be greater than 2 and must be odd eg 3,5,7,9...
var blurCircle = imageTools.padImage(circle,9);
blurCircle = imageTools.applyConvolutionFilter(blurCircle,blurFilter)
var sun =  imageTools.createImage(64,64);
grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(32,32,0,32,32,32);
grad.addColorStop(0,"#FF0");
grad.addColorStop(1,"#A40");
sun.ctx.fillStyle = grad;
sun.ctx.arc(32,32,32 -2,0, Math.PI * 2);
sun.ctx.fill();
var sunBlur = imageTools.padImage(sun,17);
blurFilter = imageTools.createBlurConvolutionArray({size:17,power:1}); // size must be greater than 2 and must be odd eg 3,5,7,9...
sunBlur = imageTools.applyConvolutionFilter(sunBlur,blurFilter);

var particles = [];
var createParticle = function(x,y,dx,dy){
    var dir = Math.atan2(y-ch,x-cw);
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y-ch,2)+Math.pow(x-cw,2));
    var v = Math.sqrt(GRAV / dist); // get apporox orbital speed
    return {
        x : x,
        y : y,
        dx : dx + Math.cos(dir + Math.PI/2) * v, // set orbit speed at tangent
        dy : dy + Math.sin(dir + Math.PI/2) * v, 
        s : (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random())/4 + 0.5, // scale
        v : (Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random()) / 3 + 2, // glow vary rate
    };
}
var depthSort = function(a,b){
    return b.y - a.y;
}
var updateParticles = function(){
    var i,p,f,dist,dir;
    for(i = 0; i < particles.length; i ++){
        p = particles[i];
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cw-p.x,2)+Math.pow(ch-p.y,2));
        dir = Math.atan2(ch-p.y,cw-p.x);
        f = GRAV * 1 / (dist * dist);
        p.dx += Math.cos(dir) * f;
        p.dy += Math.sin(dir) * f;
        p.x += p.dx;
        p.y += p.dy;
        p.rx = ((p.x - cw ) / (p.y + h)) * h + cw;
        p.ry = ((p.y - ch ) / (p.y + h)) * h * -0.051+ ch;
        //p.ry = ((h-p.y) - ch)  * 0.1 + ch;
        p.rs = (p.s / (p.y + h)) * h
    }
    particles.sort(depthSort)
}

var drawParticles = function(){
    var i,j,p,f,dist,dir;
    // draw   behind the sun
    for(i = 0; i < particles.length; i ++){
        p = particles[i];
        if(p.y - ch < 0){
            break;
        }
        ctx.setTransform(p.rs,0,0,p.rs,p.rx,p.ry);
        ctx.drawImage(circle,-IMAGE_SIZE_HALF,-IMAGE_SIZE_HALF);
        
    }
    // draw glow for behind the sun
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
    var iw = -blurCircle.width/2;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j ++){
        p = particles[j];
        ctx.globalAlpha = ((Math.sin(globalTime / (50 * p.v)) + 1) / 2) *  0.6 + 0.4;
        var scale = (1-(Math.sin(globalTime / (50 * p.v)) + 1) / 2) *  0.6 + 0.6;
        ctx.setTransform(p.rs * 1.5 * scale,0,0,p.rs * 1.5* scale,p.rx,p.ry);
        ctx.drawImage(blurCircle,iw,iw);
        // second pass to intensify the glow
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
        ctx.setTransform(p.rs * 1.1,0,0,p.rs * 1.1,p.rx,p.ry);
        ctx.drawImage(blurCircle,iw,iw);
    }
   
    // draw the sun
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";      
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(sun,-sun.width/2,-sun.height/2);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";    
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(sunBlur,-sunBlur.width/2,-sunBlur.height/2);
    var scale = Math.sin(globalTime / 100) *0.5 + 1;
    ctx.globalAlpha = (Math.cos(globalTime / 100) + 1) * 0.2 + 0.4;;
    ctx.setTransform(1 + scale,0,0,1 + scale,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(sunBlur,-sunBlur.width/2,-sunBlur.height/2);
    
    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";      
    // draw   in front the sun
    for(j = i; j < particles.length; j ++){
        p = particles[j];
        if(p.y > -h){ // don't draw past the near view plane
            ctx.setTransform(p.rs,0,0,p.rs,p.rx,p.ry);
            ctx.drawImage(circle,-IMAGE_SIZE_HALF,-IMAGE_SIZE_HALF);
        }
        
    }
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
    var iw = -blurCircle.width/2;
    for(j = i; j < particles.length; j ++){
        p = particles[j];
        if(p.y > -h){ // don't draw past the near view plane
            ctx.globalAlpha = ((Math.sin(globalTime / (50 * p.v)) + 1) / 2) *  0.6 + 0.4;
            var scale = (1-(Math.sin(globalTime / (50 * p.v)) + 1) / 2) *  0.6 + 0.6;
            ctx.setTransform(p.rs * 1.5 * scale,0,0,p.rs * 1.5* scale,p.rx,p.ry);
            ctx.drawImage(blurCircle,iw,iw);
            // second pass to intensify the glow
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
            ctx.setTransform(p.rs * 1.1,0,0,p.rs * 1.1,p.rx,p.ry);
            ctx.drawImage(blurCircle,iw,iw);
        }
    }

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";    
}


var addParticles = function(count){
    var ww = (h-10)* 2;
    var cx = cw - ww/2;
    var cy = ch - ww/2;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i ++){
        particles.push(createParticle(cx + Math.random() * ww,cy + Math.random() * ww, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5));
    }
}


function display(){  // put code in here
    if(particles.length === 0){
        addParticles(NUM_PARTICLES);
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,w,h)
    updateParticles();
    drawParticles();

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";       
}
function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```